# Split a sequence with operators and numbers on the operators or on the numbers

Tags: java, regex

So I have this regex used on java:

```
String eq = "5*i+-6-7+-i*5"
String[] equation_numbers = eq.split("(?<=[^+*/-])[+*/-]");
```

and somehow it works and I'll have:

`[5, i, -6, 7, -i, 5]`

My questions are:
Why does it work ? ( I really cant understand)
How can I make a regex in the same style and take only the operators ?

For example:

```
String eq = "5*i+-6-7+-i*5"
String[] equation_operators = eq.split(...);
```

and the result:

`[*, +, -, +, *]`

Comment: The output presented in the Question isn't entirely what the code will give you. It will give you this String array: `[5, i, -6, 7, -i, 5]`. There's no `-` on the `7`.

Comment: I'm afraid the title of your post will not help others to find this post if they want to know the same thing. I think you should try to find a better title. The regex uses these three parts: positive lookbehind, character class and negative character class. Knowing the names will help you find these so you can read about them.

Comment: @Scratte yes you are right, there is no -, but that's what I wanted.
And what title should I put then ? I dont post so often here.. so yea

Comment: I'd probably use "Split a sequence of operators and digits on the digit values.". As far as a solution to get the operators only, I'd use `((?<!\\w)-)?\\w`.

Comment: Thanks for your answers and your criticism. I was too selfish in my post and didn't think for the others or as a "wikipedia". I will keep that in mind when I will make another post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression `(?<=[^+*/-])[+*/-]` contains:

- A positive lookbehind: `(?<=[^+*/-])`
- A character class: `[+*/-]`

##### The positive lookbehind contains a negative character class

The negative character class is defined by the `^` in the beginning. And it will match everything that is **not** anyone of `+`, `*`, `/`, `-`.

The positive lookbehind will just look at any preceding character. If there's a match, it will be set to true, and the expression will proceed. A lookbehind will only look and it will "match" while looking, but once the lookahead is done, the expression will not have moved on the string to be matched, the "eq". The marker on the string will remain exactly where it was when the lookbehind began.

`(?<=[^+*/-])` will look at the preceding character, and if and only if the preceding character is **not** any of these 4, the expression is allowed to move to the next part.

If we only had the lookbehind, it would be true on any of these places:

```
5*i+-6-7+-i*5
 ^ ^  ^ ^  ^
```

everywhere else, there is either no character, or one of those 4 characters just prior.

##### The match

`[+*/-]` matches only these 4 characters and it so happens that at every place where the lookbehind returns true, one of these characters can be matched. So the result of the expression on the entire string is the marked spots above.

##### The split

`String.split(regex);` will split the string on matches. So you'll get a `String array` where the markings have been removed and those exact ones have split the result:

```
5 i -6 7 -i 5
```

#### Splitting on the digits instead

In order to split on the digits, you'll need to match those instead of the operators. `\w` is short for `[0-9A-Za-z_]`. The `-` denote ranges, so this will match your `i` as well.

The only trick is to match a preceding minus, `-`, which you can do with `((?<!\\w)-)?`. This is a negative lookbehind. It will check the preceding character and if it finds it, the result is false, and it will not be able to proceed. If it does not find a `\w`, the result is true, and it will be able to proceed, and it will proceed by matching a `-`. This will ensure that it will only attempt to match a `-` when there's another operator before the `-`. The `?` after the entire expression makes it optional, so if the lookahead returns false, this entire thing is just skipped.

Now all that is needed is to match the word character after the optional `-`, with `\w`, and the expression becomes:

`((?<!\\w)-)?\\w`

where the escape character is escaped for use as a litteral into a Java `String`.

Comment: It will fail for input `5*i-+6-7+-i*5` besides split using `((?<!\\w)-)?\\w` leaves an empty string at the start.

Comment: @anubhava Yes, you're right. I assumed only `-` would be used in front of a digit. About the empty first element. I do not see a way out of that when using `String.split`, since we need to match the first digit to remove it. So either it needs to be removed before the split, or from the array after the split.

Comment: @anubhava You're free to add to your post that it avoids the problem that my solution has. Yours is indeed a nice solution. I only feel that it needs a little more explanation to it :) I only posted this because I wanted to explain the expression in the Question, and I felt the post would be incomplete without a solution to split on the digits.

Comment: Sorry but I avoid adding criticism of other solutions to promote my already posted answer. It is upto OP to see all available solutions and chose whatever works out for him. If OP wants some clarification then I would surely explain further in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `split` use `matcher` and collect all the results in a `List` using this regex:

```
(?<![+*/-])[+*/-]
```

This regex matches one of the `[+*/-]` operators as long as these operators are not preceded by same operators.

[RegEx Code](https://regex101.com/r/D772NQ/1)

You may use this code in Java:

```
String eq = "5*i+-6-7+-i*5";
String re = "(?<![+*/-])[+*/-]";

List<String> matches = Pattern.compile(re)
    .matcher(eq)
    .results()
    .map(MatchResult::group)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
//=> [*, +, -, +, *]
```